# How do I run a Jenkins job where user can enter a date and time value?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wanted to run a jenkins job by accepting a date  and time field (in format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm) from user.

Comment: It is a kind of duplicate, but the answers of the linked question are a little outdated.

Answer (score 4):

Use parameterized build to get user input at the start of your job. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Sample pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'slave'}
    parameters {
        string(name: 'DateTime', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter date & time in format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Build
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enhance the answer from @ben5556 with the [date parameter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/date-parameter)

[image: Date parameter]